# i am getting this on npm run dev " Invalid configuration object"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack

> [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
> configuration.module.rules[26] should be one of these:
> ["..." | object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
> -> A rule.
> Details:
> configuration.module.rules[22] has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
> object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
> -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
> * configuration.module.rules[23] has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
> object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
> -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
> * configuration.module.rules[24] has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
> object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
> -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
> * configuration.module.rules[25] has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
> object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
> -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
> * configuration.module.rules[26] has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
> object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
> -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.

here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const WebpackShellPlugin = require('./lib');

module.exports = {
  watch: true,
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test/entry.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 devServer: {
  inline: false,
  // contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test')
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
     { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' }
  ]
 },
 plugins: [
   new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildStart:['node test.js'], onBuildEnd:['echo 
   "Webpack End"'], safe: true, verbose: true}),
   new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
 ]
};
```

Comment: Let share us your configuration file as well

Comment: According to `configuration.module.rules[22] has an unknown property 'loaders'`, you have a `loaders` in webpack configuration file, but I don't see one from you `webpack.config.js` file.